# Using await in ASP.NET webform pages inline code

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-4.5

If I have some inline code in my ASP.NET webforms page (in .NET 4.5), e.g.

```
<li>
   <% =ListItemWithPrice("Widget")%> 
</li>
```

and I want to make `ListItemWithPrice` async, is it possible to await it on the page? I know I can use

```
<li>
   <% =ListItemWithPrice("Widget").Result%> 
</li>
```

but that'll just block while waiting for the Task to complete, which isn't really any help (and might even be worse). Ideally, I'd like to use

```
<li>
   <% =await ListItemWithPrice("Widget")%> 
</li>
```

but that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have inline await statements in a Page, but you can do it from code-behind using Page.RegisterAsyncTask.  See http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/aspnet-45/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-45 for an example.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no, await cannot be used in this way. This would work if the await keyword would generate an ajax request and the corresponding callback function to call for when the request is done.